# Codeigniter Ajax request URL issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, url-routing

I am using codeigniter version 3+, Jquery version 3+. I am trying to get data through ajax request but it does not return anything.  And when I inspect and see its request url is wrong but did not get how i modify that.

> Ajax request

```
 var site_url = '<?=base_url()?>';
 var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value');
     $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                dataType : 'json',
                url: '<?=base_url()?>'+'index.php/talika_12/get_data_by_id_ajax',
                data: {user_id:id},
                success: function(data) {
                   alert(data);
                   $('#inst_name').text(data.talika_12_user_name);
                   $('#inst_account_no').text(data.talika_12_user_account_no);
            }
       });
```

> Controller

```
 public function get_data_by_id_ajax(){
      $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
      $data = $this->talika_12_m->get_data_by_id($user_id);
      $ajax_response_data = array(
        'talika_12_user_name' => $data[0]->talika_12_user_name ,
        'talika_12_user_account_no' => $data[0]->talika_12_user_account_no , 
      );
      echo json_encode($ajax_response_data);
}
```

> Model

```
 public function get_data_by_id($id){
       $where_clause = array('talika_12_user_id' => $id);
       $this->db->limit(1);
       $val = $this->db->get_where('table_12', $where_clause)->result();
      return $val;
 }
```

> Get request url is ( Request URL:http://localhost/test/codeIgniter/talika_12/%3C?=base_url()?%3Eindex.php/talika_12/get_data_by_id_ajax
>   )

Comment: The problem is in the url of your ajax

Comment: You can try like this url: "<?=base_url('index.php/talika_12/get_data_by_id_ajax')?>"

Comment: Why not you simplify it as, `url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/talika_12/get_data_by_id_ajax'); ?>"`?

Comment: after trying your method url is this ---- http://localhost/test/codeIgniter/index.php/talika_12/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url(%27index.php/talika_12/get_data_by_id_ajax%27);%20?%3E

Comment: what is your expexted request url? try removing base_url `url : 'index.php/talika_12/get_data_by_id_ajax'`

Comment: If that ajax function is in separate JS file you can't invoke PHP code there. What you can do is to put that function at the end of view file or at beginning of the view file set baseUrl variable globally. Like <script>var baseUrl = '<?php echo base_url();?>';</script> loaded just in head section of page before file with ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value');
    $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                dataType : 'json',
                url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/talika_12/get_data_by_id_ajax'",
                data: {user_id:id},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                   $('#inst_name').text(data.talika_12_user_name);
                   $('#inst_account_no').text(data.talika_12_user_account_no);


            }
       });
```

changed url portion `url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/talika_12/get_data_by_id_ajax'",` otherwise you can use `url:<?= site_url('talika_12/get_data_by_id_ajax')`

Comment: what did you get url in this case -@Destroyer.0211